# How to renewcommand in newcommand

Tags: macros

I have a macro that I use to write units (so that I can write exponents easily), in math or in text mode.

I would like to change the definition of `\mu` in `\upmu` (from the `upgreek` package) only in this macro (not for standard math). This is what I wrote:

```
\newcommand{\U}[1]{%
    \renewcommand{\mu}{\upmu}
    \ensuremath{\mathrm{~#1}}%
}
```

It works, but I get an error at compilation:

```
ERROR: Argument of \@caption has an extra }.

--- TeX said ---
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.117 ... bla 30\U{\mu K} bla bla}

--- HELP ---
From the .log file...

I've run across a `}' that doesn't seem to match anything.
For example, `\def\a#1{...}' and `\a}' would produce
this error. If you simply proceed now, the `\par' that
I've just inserted will cause me to report a runaway
argument that might be the root of the problem. But if
your `}' was spurious, just type `2' and it will go away.
```

for the incriminated code:

```
\caption{bla bla 30\U{\mu K} bla bla}
```

Comment: Add `\protect` before `\renewcommand`. Also add `%` after `{\upmu}`.

Comment: Do you want it as an answer?

Comment: Yes, but if you could explain very briefly (or give a link) what `\protect` does in this case, it would be useful.

Comment: OK. Made it as an answer. BTW, I didn't welcomed you here yet. Here I am: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: I've just realized that you're a member of TeX.SX from over a year... You had surely already read our starter guide time ago. I apologize.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Fragile commands like `\renewcommand` have to be `\protect`ed when used in moving arguments like the one of `\caption` (see [What is the difference between Fragile and Robust commands?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4736/what-is-the-difference-between-fragile-and-robust-commands) for more info).

Moreover, you have to add a trailing `%` whenever you don't want to insert extra space (see [What is the use of percent signs (%) at the end of lines?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7453/what-is-the-use-of-percent-signs-at-the-end-of-lines)).

So you should change your definition to

```
\newcommand{\U}[1]{%
    \protect\renewcommand{\mu}{\upmu}%
    \ensuremath{\mathrm{~#1}}%
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You want to use

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\U}[1]{%
   \ensuremath{\let\mu\upmu\,#1}%
}
```

so you don't have to worry about untimely expansion of `\U`. Note that the proper spacing is `\,` rather than `~`. Instead of `\let\mu\upmu` you could use `\renewcommand{\mu}{\upmu}` that's only less efficient.

However this is still wrong: the `K` should be upright, assuming it means the kelvin unit.

Here's how you should be doing it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{textgreek}
\sisetup{
  text-micro=\textmu,
  math-micro=\text{\textmu},
}

\begin{document}
\listoffigures
\begin{figure}[htp]
\caption{bla bla \SI{30}{\micro\kelvin} bla bla}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is something like

```
\newcommand{\U}[1]{\bgroup\renewcommand{\mu}{\upmu}%%
   \ensuremath{\mathrm{~#1}}\egroup}
```

When you call this from within `\caption`, write

```
\caption{bla bla 30\protect\U{\mu K} bla bla}
```

Comment: Is there any adverse effect if one `\protect`s the `\renewcommand` as suggested by karlkoeller?

Comment: karlkoeller's solution is more convenient as I don't have to think of putting a `\protect` in front of each usage of my `\U` command.